# Android default drawable over custom one

Tags: android, android-drawable

I created custom drawable for `Switch` but when I apply it to switch item using `android:drawableRight="@drawable/switch_selector"` it looks like this:
[image]
[image]

How to get rid of those default view? Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Android Switch you need to set the Drawables for each of the parts. The first part is the `android:thumb` which is the Drawable that moves from left to right.
[image] 
The second part is the `android:track` which is the Drawable that the `android:thumb` slides on. [image]If you do not mind having no animations you can set the  `android:thumbTint="@color/transparent` and the `android:trackTint="@color/transparent`which will remove the default view.